# Writing small amount of data to cassandra table in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra

I need to write some small amount of data to a cassandra table in a spark application. The data is not an RDD, and it is just a double value. How to do this in a Spark application using Java API?

Thanks for any hint.

Answer (score 1):

As a quick solution you can use sc.parallelize and save RDD to Cassandra as usual.

If you need to run a query you can use CassandraConnector pool like in doc:

```
  val connector = CassandraConnector(sc.getConf)
  connector.withSessionDo(session => ...)
```

https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/1_connecting.md